# Combination of searches - standardized format?

Tags: php, search, standards

While thinking about how to best combine search results from different resources on a site (e.g. blog software, forum software, pages etc.) it appeared to me that it would be pretty neat to have a standardized format (possibly XML) to return search results. This could consist of title, excerpt and more meta information like time, author etc...

Ever heard of such a thing or do I have to program it myself? ;)

Other ideas are, of course, welcome, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like RSS-ish...

Standard RSS tags include: *Title*, *Description*, and *Link*. You can add others like *Category*, *pubDate*, *GUID*, *Author* and more.

This format can be used for sending search criteria, and for retrieving search results. Just handle the incoming XML, and form an XML document to send back.

Comment: Are there RSS feeds for *searching*?

Comment: Franz, yes, you can submit search criteria in the form of an XML document. And you can return the results in the form of an RSS document.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't realize that there were RSS feeds providing a search feature, too (wouldn't that happen via URL parameters?)...

Comment: Franz, that would depend on you. If you use GET, then yes. If you use POST then no.

Comment: Yeah, obviously... I was just making sure I understood you correctly. Thanks then ;)